# Why is there a " - 1" in the pn-junction current equation

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

I was studying the Ideal Current–Voltage Relationship and was wondering why there is a "-1" in the pn-junction current equation for a pn junction diode.

﻿[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

When Vd equals zero, the exponential term becomes 1, since any real number to the zero power equals one. Subtracting 1 from this gives zero current for zero voltage.